# Issue executing mysql from script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

My, Batch-Script looks like this:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root <  C:\xampp\file.sql
pause
```

But after it stops the following is displayed:

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root  0< C:\xampp\file.sql
>
> "cant find the path"

If I copy-paste this into `cmd.exe` it works fine.

Comment: Are both your secret `{PATH}`s fully specified or relative to the current working directory? _Those `{PATH}`s are the only important pieces of information relevant to your problem and yet exactly what you've kept from us!_

Comment: Both of them are fully specified. Like:
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe

The strange thing is that it works when i manually type that into the command line. I think the "<" is making problems but I dont know why...

Comment: [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49223010/edit) to include exactly what is failing to work as a batch file.

Comment: The error message with the exact content you have shown can only mean there is either no accessible file named `"mysql.exe"` in a directory named `"C:\xampp\mysql\bin"` or no accessible file named `"file.sql"` in a directory named `"C:\xampp"`. Is there no password to enter for the `root` user and have you alternatively tried right clicking on the batch file to **run As administrator**?